# how to sort default td inside table alphabetically with javascript jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I am using this table and script for sorting alphabetically the data inside the `td`:

```
<button type=button>Sort Options</button>

<table class="table-data">
  <tr>
    <td class="filename">C</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="filename">A</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="filename">D</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="filename">B</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And the jquery:

```
$('button').click(function() {
  var options = $('table.table-data td');
  var arr = options.map(function(_, o) {
    return {
        t: $(o).text(),
        v: o.value
    };
  }).get();
  arr.sort(function(o1, o2) {
    return o1.t > o2.t ? 1 : o1.t < o2.t ? -1 : 0;
  });
  options.each(function(i, o) {
    console.log(i);
    o.value = arr[i].v;
    $(o).text(arr[i].t);
  });
});
```

Now the sorting happens when clicking on the button. How can I make the sorting default when loading the page? (without clicking button)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same code you have as an event handler can be used as a named function. Then if you want it to run on page load, just call it on page load!

```js
// Have it a named function instead of an event handler
function sortTds(){
  var options = $('table.table-data td');
  var arr = options.map(function(_, o) {
    return {
        t: $(o).text(),
        v: o.value
    };
  }).get();
  arr.sort(function(o1, o2) {
    return o1.t > o2.t ? 1 : o1.t < o2.t ? -1 : 0;
  });
  options.each(function(i, o) {
    console.log(i);
    o.value = arr[i].v;
    $(o).text(arr[i].t);
  });
}

// Call the function on page load
sortTds();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="table-data">
  <tr>
    <td class="filename">C</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="filename">A</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="filename">D</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="filename">B</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```